# How to choose config file as command-line argument and present result in the console while maintaining modularization?

Tags: javascript, configuration, command-line-arguments

`config.ts`:

```
export const data = 'Config';
```

`process.ts`:

```
import { data } from "./config.ts";
const calculated = data + ' is used.'
export {calculated}
```

`main.ts`:

```
import { calculated } from "./process.ts";
console.log(calculated)
```

```
> deno run main.ts
Config is used.
```

Now, I want to be able to choose configuration via command-line argument. That is:

```
> deno run main.ts config1
Config1 is used.
> deno run main.ts config2
Config2 is used.
> deno run main.ts config3
Config3 is used.
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the static `import` and `Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'configToUse' before initialization`, I use [dynamic imports](https://javascript.info/modules-dynamic-imports) and wrap everything inside functions. The code becomes:

`process.ts`:

```
async function calculate(configToUse) {
    const pathToConfig = './' + configToUse + '.ts'
    const config = await import(pathToConfig)
    return config.data + ' is used.'
    }
export {calculate}
```

`main.ts`:

```
import { calculate } from "./process.ts";
const configToUse = Deno.args[0]

calculate(configToUse).then((result) => {
    console.log(result)
})
```